# Write to file in PHP with a variable as the filename

Tags: php, forms, variables, filenames

I have a script that will write a given string to a text file...

I have experience in writing to txt files via PHP....

I would like to write to a file when a form is submitted, and I have the script working to write to file " users/user_txt/$username.txt ".

But it saves the filename as $username.txt.

This is the code:

```
$fp = fopen('users/user_txt/$username.txt', 'a+');
$fwrite = fwrite($fp, "," . $log_write);
```

This creates a blank text file and appends it, or creates file when no file exists...

However, it saves the filename as `/$username.txt`.

I am grabbing the variable "$username" from the form, and this echo's correct...

But I need it to actually create the filename as:

```
DJ-PIMP.txt
```

If I submit my username as DJ-PIMP on the form...

Let’s pretend I fill the form and enter username as `dave123`.

I need the script to write to file like this:

```
$fp = fopen('users/user_txt/dave123.txt', 'a+');
```

How would I code this so that when I submit the form (as soon as form submitted, the variable $username would be 'dave123').

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set file name using user inputted variable in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484736/set-file-name-using-user-inputted-variable-in-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code example you have above uses single quotes, which takes everything literally.  Use:

```
$fp = fopen("users/user_txt/$username.txt",'a+'); $fwrite = fwrite($fp, "," . $log_write);
```

Or

```
$fp = fopen('users/user_txt/'.$username.'.txt', 'a+'); $fwrite = fwrite($fp, "," . $log_write);
```

Comment: $fp = fopen('users/user_txt/'.$username.'.txt', 'a+'); <<< this works thanks

Comment: Paul thanks for the code box edit, posted answer from my droid so didnt have formatting options... DJ PIMP lol not sure why the the double quote solution would give errors they should be equivalent